# Passing multiple arguments to java function via scriptEngine in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, scriptengine

I am using Java script engine to run javascript at run time and I have a java method like so

```
public void func(Object x, Object... args)
{//CODE..}
```

And I am trying to call that method via the script engine

```
classX myClass = new classX();
scriptEngine.bind("myClass", myClass);

scriptEngine.eval("myClass.func(1, 2,3,4,5)");
```

But the method wont run.
all I get is null, no error.

Answer (score 1):

try using put instead of bind...its work for me
scriptEngine.put("myClass", myClass);